# On functions and their linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

How would you access the following problem:

> Show that the set of functions $$ \phi_n : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$$$\phi_n(x) = \frac{1}{n+x}$$for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ is linearly independent.

Since we can not obtain the zero vector (only by dividing a zero) and we can not represent on of the created vectors by combination of others, we know it is linearly independent.

Comment: Show that the *set of functions* is...

Comment: A linear combination can have *more* than two vectors.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla yes but still it is independent right?

Comment: The problem is to *prove* that *in fact* "we can not represent..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose
$$\lambda_1\frac{1}{n_1+x}+\cdots+\lambda_k\frac{1}{n_k+x}=0$$
for all $x$. Each function $\phi_i$ is continuous  except at $x=-n_i$, so the sum is discontinuous at $x=-n_i$ except if $\lambda_i=0$.

Comment: but $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Comment: They are rational functions. You can extend each function to $\Bbb R\setminus$ a finite set of points.

Comment: so is it correct to state: the set of functions is linearly independent because $\lambda_1\frac{1}{n_1+x}+\cdots+\lambda_k\frac{1}{n_k+x}=0$ is only $0$ when each $\lambda_i$ is $0$

Comment: @Mainviel, right.